# Oracle 11g can't log with sys user

Tags: oracle, authentication

Today i meet a werid thing:I can't log on remote server Oracle database with sys user!
The username/password is sys/123,and my colleage could!this situation maintained still now.

But i can log on with an normal user,not a system dba.This is no privilege limit.Why? It's so werid.

This error info:

```
ORA-01017:invalid username/password;logon denied.
```

The oracle version:11g.

Log on tool:PL/SQL

need other info?Is local install oracle 10g cause the problem?

On the command line:

```
SQL>show parameter remote_login_passwordfile  The value is：EXCLUSIVE
```

Comment: Does it work with SQLPLUS? You should also try if it works as `SYSOPER` or `SYSDBA`: `sqlplus 'SYS/PASSWORD@DB AS SYSDBA'

Comment: If it works from your coworkers computer, be sure you both use the same `tnsnames.ora`

Comment: @marderh I think tnsnames.ora is not the point.I checked right now,both was the same:192.168.1.88 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.88)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

Comment: @marderh in sqlplus it was the same error:C:\Users\Administrator>sqlplus sys/123@192.168.1.88 as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 星期四 8月 8 17:29:23 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


请输入用户名(Please input username):

Comment: @Dolphin You can't connect as simple user with `sys` account, only as sysdba. And you can't pass `as sysdba` in comand-line parameter. So try to run `sqlplus /nolog` and in `SQL>` prompt issue connect command: `conn sys/123@192.168.1.88 as sysdba` .

Comment: @Dolphin Sorry, it can be done from command line, just use quotes: `C:>sqlplus "sys/123@192.168.1.88 as sysdba"` .

Comment: @Dolphin Is you password really 123? If not then check if any non-ANSI symbols present in password and compare Oracle client locale settings on both computers.

Comment: @ThinkJet ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.     SQL> conn sys/123@192.168.1.88 as sysdba

Comment: @ThinkJet Maybe that's the problem,the password is 123,I promise.The remote server charactset is AL32UTF8,my computer characterset is ZHS16GBK.But the point is:Why i use normal user can login????Like eca/123

Comment: you can also allow or deny users in the listerner based on the ip-adress: Look into sqlnet.ora on the server.

Comment: @Dolphin Did you install 2 versions together (10g and 11g)?

Comment: @ThinkJet No,my local computer install Oracle 10g,The remote computer installed Oracle 11g.And my coworker install Oracle 11g local,I think maybe the version problem,but i can login with unsys user,that's make me gloomy!

Answer (score 3):

Solved:This problem bother me 2 day.Now the problem has fixed in 3 steps:

```
1.login the remote server and login as sys/123 as sysdba.
2.reset the password ( alter user sys identified by 123;)
3.relogin the oracle use sys,done!
```